# Highlighting skills not directly relevant to your major on resume

Tags: resume

I am studying mechanical engineering but have taken several computer science and software engineering courses like Reinforcement Learning, Algorithms, and Machine Learning although I am not considered to have a specialization or concentration in Computer Science or Data Science. How should I highlight this so that I don't get overlooked by employers who think a mechanical engineering student wouldn't be suitable for their software engineering role?

Comment: Don't have just one resume. Always taylor your resume to the job you're applying to. When you apply to a job where skills in machine learning are useful, then highlight those skills.

Comment: Also, if you're a student with no professional experience, it makes sense to have a "Personal projects" section in your resume, where you mention the projects you've worked on in your free time. If you've done some cool projects using computer science, you can mention them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you are interesting in software engineering positions? This won't be a problem. I was an electrical engineering major and was highly sought after for software engineering positions and have had a 25+ year career doing so. I wasn't considered a software expert either, but took courses in Assembly, Pascal and C++ programming in college but did receive a certificate from another university in Unix and C programming.

You can add a "Skills" section and then list our your experience level with various technologies, course work, projects, etc. You can also mention these facts in an "Introduction". You can call our your software experience in a cover letter. If you have any web sites, etc. that you have developed or worked on, you can also list those on your resume to afford the manager the ability to directly interact with your work. I am sure there are web sites out there with sample resumes as well. Lastly, does your college offer any resume advice? My college did and they helped us write our first resume so I would suggest looking to see if you have a placement center that can offer that service.

It is VERY common for various engineering students to seek employment in software development and recruiters and hiring managers understand that varying engineering disciplines graduate students with a background in computer programming since we spend a lot of time building applications to perform simulations on our coursework. I was a hiring engineering manager at one point and hired software developers with all kinds of degrees from CS to ME to political science!

You'll be in good shape. Don't sweat it.

Answer (score -1):

Now, this does depend on the industry - but having cross-over knowledge can be extremely prized. Being able to talk Engineer to the Engineers and Dev to the Devs can be massively helpful.

The way to highlight it is to do just that - talk about what projects you've done (even if they are just personal projects) and your experience etc.